# hibernate hql - return updated rows id list after execute update query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql

I'm using Hibernate Query Language(HQL) with Oracle database in my Java spring MVC application. I have write an HQL update query in this way:

```
String hql = "update " + MyModel.class.getName() + " e set e.field = " + value + " where ..."
//Acquiring session
...
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

The `executeUpdate()` method returns number of updated rows. But I want to get a list of the ids of updated rows after executing the update query. Is there any way of doing this in HQL?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there is no such functionality in JPA/Hibernate. But you can create native query and use native SQL. I do not know oracle, but in PostgreSQL I would write :

```
String sql = "update table set field = :values where ... returning id";
Query query = session.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("value", value);
List ids = query.list();
```

May be oracle have similar functional and this will help you.

Comment: Where is the documentation for this? Can something similar be done for Mysql? My question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819457/hibernate-how-to-retrieve-affected-ids-list-after-query-update

Answer (score 0):

Blaze-Persistence, a library that works on top of JPA/Hibernate, adds support for this.

Here some more information about that: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#returning-from-update-statement